# Buttons fail to work after AJAX Div tag html reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, perl, post

When the button is clicked, script completes an Ajax post, then returns new HTML into VAR divReload that updates the contents of the specific div tag. Problem I'm having is once this updates successfully, the same buttons inside that div no longer work. Any thoughts?

```
 <input type='button' class='all-boxes' value='All Boxes' submit-val='$ord_id' 
    single- rate='2' submit-wave='$select_wave'>

 <script type=\"text/javascript\">

\$(\".all-boxes\").live(\"click\", function() {

   var uccId = \$(this).attr('ucc-val');
   var orderId = \$(this).attr('submit-val');
   var singleRate = \$(this).attr('single-rate');
   var waveId = \$(this).attr('submit-wave');

   var imgBox = \"#img-box-\"+orderId;
   var textBox = \"#text-box-\"+orderId;
   var divReload = \"#div-\"+orderId;

\$(imgBox).fadeIn(500);

    \$.ajax({
               url: '/cgi-bin/sys/prod/DC/rate_quote_test/rate_quote5.pl/',
               type: 'POST',
               data: 'single_rate=' + singleRate +'&wave_number=' + waveId + 
                     '&single_ord_id=' + orderId + '&single_ucc_id=' + uccId,

               success: function(result) {
                \$(divReload).html(result);
                var alertReload = \"#alert-me-\"+orderId;
                \$(alertReload).toggle();
                alert(\$(alertReload).html());
            }
  });

        return false;

});
```

";

Comment: can we see a bit more of your html page structure?  where is the div that is being reloaded?  is this bit of code what is being returned from the ajax request?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to either reattach the click events after you update the form with the new div, or use the `.live()` [event binding](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method of jQuery.

**UPDATE**

It looks like you're already using `.live()` In that case, the button information that is coming back is probably not matching the `$(".all-boxes")` selector.

Comment: it looks like he IS using live.